# How to send dynamic value in css clac()

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

I want to send a dynamic data in calc() of csss on every change ,Showing you some code to understand the requirement

I am getting my data in class countDist and want send in place of 33 in calc function

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-group">
  <div class="countDist"></div>
  <div class="progress sm">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red" style="width: calc((100%)-33/100)"></div </div>
  </div>
```

```js
$.getJSON('timeLineDataforDistToState', {
  stateCode: $(this).val(),
  ajax: 'true'
}, function(data) {
  var a = data;
  $('.countDist').html(a);
});
```

Comment: if you already using javascript, `calc()` is irrelevant

Comment: @ZohirSalak I have to do using jsp,I am creating some progress bar,can u pls help me out,If i am sending static value 33 then its working fine but i have to send dynamic data on every change thats coming in my countDist class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use CSS in JS like this :

```
$('.countDist').css('width', '<YOUR_VALUE>');
```

Not sure it works, it's been a long time since I've used jQuery

Comment: thanx for you contribution ,but i think you didin't got my question,the value is coming in class countdist